# How to test whether a string doesn't contain specified letters in bash

Tags: bash

In a program I am writing I need to check whether a string contains characters not in another string e.g.:

```sh
if [ $string ?? "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789" ]; then
    echo $string isnt alphanumeric
fi
```

or

```sh
if [ $string ?? "ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]; then
    echo $string isnt alphabetic
fi
```

Where `??` is the mystery operation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `[[ $string =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+$ ]]`

Comment: @anubhava can I do this with any string?

Comment: Didn't understand your question. May be you need to add more clarity in question

Comment: @anubhava sure I have changed the question a bit, I hope you understand my question now

Comment: Your title says you want to test if it *doesn't* contain letters, but the text asks how to test if it *does* contain those letters. Which is it?

Comment: @Arale Why wouldn't it work with any string? A string is a string.

Comment: I guess the OP means, for any reference string (not necessarily `"ABCDE...56789"`, and not necessarily hard-coded in the script)

Answer (score 4):

In bash, within `[[...]]`, the `==` and `!=` operators are *pattern matching* operators, so

```sh
validChars="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

if [[ $string != *["$validChars"]* ]]; then
    echo "$string does NOT contain any of $validChars"
fi
```

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b

---

To test that a string ONLY contains characters in $validChars, we can use bash's [extended pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

```sh
if [[ $string == +(["$validChars"]) ]]; then
    echo "$string ONLY contains chars in $validChars"
fi
if [[ $string != +(["$validChars"]) ]]; then
    echo "string is empty or contains some character not in $validChars"
fi
```